# How to publish results on the Web from local MQTT non-Internet network?

Tags: pi-3b+, web-server, mqtt

I'm making a project where I have a local no-Internet MQTT network (scheme below).

Devices (except for RPi 3B+) needs to work outside so I can't provide them Internet access. The purpose of RPi 3B+ node is to receive sensor data and transfer it to Web server in graphic, easy-to-analyse way.

**The question is:** Is it possibile to switch automatically networks by RPi 3B+ node and how can I make it?

Also if anyone could recommend solution for collecting and showing data in Web server I'd really appreciate that. I'm quite newbie and it's important to me to keep the project in not over complicated way.

Thank You in advance.

**Scheme:**

**Web server ~ . ~  . ~ RPi 3B+ ~ ~ ~ RPi 0W ~ ~ ~ ESP32 -- sensor**

**~ . ~ . ~** Wi-Fi connection in network with Internet access

**~ ~ ~** Wi-Fi connection in network without Internet access (MQTT network)

**RPi 3B+** and **ESP32** - MQTT clients

**RPi 0W** - MQTT broker

Comment: so, I take it the RPI0W is a wifi access point and you also have another access point (not shown in your "scheme" that web server connects to), and want the pi3 to switch between the pi0 and this other access point

Comment: yes, this "another access point" is actually my home router with Internet ;) also I did change the RPi 0W to AP itself, Your way of thinking is exactly correct

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the [AWS IoT Greengrass](https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/) service.  The Greengrass framework is specifically geared towards this type of architecture.  The RasPi would be a IoT Greengrass Core device, and the ESP32s would be local IoT devices that communicate on the local network with the RasPi.  The RasPi can be intermittently connected to the internet to transfer data collected from the ESP32s up to the cloud for processing via AWS IoT analytics.

[image]

-*Original Image from [AWS IoT Greengrass landing page](https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/)* -

It has a bit of a learning curve, but you can experiment on the AWS free tier so there is no cost (other than the time to learn how to set it all up).

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: Thank You very much, but unfortunately I have deadline coming and I don't know if in this project I have enough time to change general idea